# When creating hash + salt for password is there a way to avoid saving the salt as a separate field in the database

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-core, salt, password-encryption

I am using the following code to generate a hash and salt for a user password:

```
        byte[] salt = new byte[128 / 8];
        using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
        {
            rng.GetBytes(salt);
        }

        string hashed = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
            password: password,
            salt: salt,
            prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1,
            iterationCount: 10000,
            numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));
    }

user.passwordHash = hashed;
user.passwordSalt = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(salt);
```

**Then to validate I am doing the following:**

```
string hash = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
    password: passwordToValidate,
    salt: Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passwordSalt),
    prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1,
    iterationCount: 10000,
    numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));

return passwordHash == hash;
```

I got this code from [this section of the asp.net core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing).

1. Is the salt typically stored in its own field the way I am doing it or is there a way to store it all in one field and then pick it apart when validating?
2. Am I properly converting the salt byte array to a string when saving to the db and back to a byte array when validating?

Comment: First question would be, why do you want to avoid to save it as separate field? A per user salt is always better than one generic salt. Because this way an attacker who gets your database will have to bruteforce the complete set of possible values for every single user instead of once for all users

Comment: @Tseng I am struggling storing the salt in the database. What would you recommend I convert it to in the code and what SQLSERVER data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Salt is typically stored in its own field, but it's not a requirement - you can store password and salt together in one field if you want to. For example, with your code salt is of fixed size (16 bytes) and your hash is also of fixed size (32 bytes). So you can store them together in one 48-byte column and can always split them without any ambiguity. Of course you should always remember then what goes first: salt or key. If you store them in a string column as base-64, like you are doing now, you can add a separator (not required) - some character which cannot appear in base64, like semicolon. Then you can store like "password_hash:salt". I'd suggest to store in binary column though.

2) You are converting it wrong. You treat it as UTF-16 encoded string, which it is not - salt is random set of bytes and not a string in any encoding. So use base-64 like you already do for hash (if you insist on storing that as string):

```
user.passwordSalt = Convert.ToBase64String(salt);
```